# C - Unable to free allocated memory

Tags: c, memory-management, crash, free

I have a problem with an application I'm currently developing. In this program I have to read huge amounts (billions) of data from text files and manage them consequently, but since it's a two students project, the reading part will be developed by my mate. For testing reason I wrote a small procedures that generates pseudo-random structures to replace what my mate will do.

The problem is the following: a big amount of the generated data (due to redundancy) can be discarded in order to free its memory. But even invoking the free() function the memory usage keeps growing. So I tried to develop a debug application that simply generates a chunk of data and immediately frees it. And repeats that for thousands of times. **Well, I can't grasp the reason, but the memory allocated to the process grows to ~1.8 GB ram and then crashes.** Why? The strangest thing, that makes me thing there's a lot I'm not understanding well, is that when the process crashes the malloc does NOT return a NULL pointer, because the process always crashes when readCycles == 6008 and bypasses the NULL check.

I already read other related topics here on StackOverflow and I understood why free() doesn't reduce the memory allocated to my process. That's fine. But why the memory usage keeps growing? Shouldn't the malloc allocate previously freed memory instead of constantly requesting new one?

This is the most relevant part of my code:

```
#define NREAD 1000
#define READCYCLES 10000
#define N_ALPHA_ILLUMINA 7
#define N_ALPHA_SOLID 5
#define SEQLEN 76

typedef struct{
    char* leftDNA;
    char* leftQuality;
    unsigned long int leftRow;
    char* rightDNA;
    char* rightQuality;
    unsigned long int rightRow;
} MatePair;


unsigned long int readCycles = 0;


MatePair* readStream(MatePair* inputStream, short* eof, unsigned long int* inputSize){

    double r;
    unsigned long int i, j;
    unsigned long int leftRow;
    int alphabet[] = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'N'};
    inputStream = (MatePair*) malloc (sizeof(MatePair) * (NREAD + 1));
    printf("%d\n", readCycles);
    if (inputStream == NULL){
        (*eof) = 1;
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NREAD; i++){
        leftRow = readCycles * NREAD + i;
        inputStream[i].leftDNA = (char*) malloc (SEQLEN);
        inputStream[i].rightDNA = (char*) malloc (SEQLEN);
        inputStream[i].leftQuality = (char*) malloc (SEQLEN);
        inputStream[i].rightQuality = (char*) malloc (SEQLEN);
        for (j = 0; j < SEQLEN; j++){
            r = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1);
            inputStream[i].leftDNA[j] = alphabet[(int)(r * 5)];
            inputStream[i].rightDNA[j] = alphabet[(int)(r * 5)];
            inputStream[i].leftQuality[j] = (char) 64 + (int)(r * 60);
            inputStream[i].rightQuality[j] = (char) 64 + (int)(r * 60);
        }
        inputStream[i].leftDNA[SEQLEN - 1] = '\0';
        inputStream[i].rightDNA[SEQLEN - 1] = '\0';
        inputStream[i].leftQuality[SEQLEN - 1] = '\0';
        inputStream[i].rightQuality[SEQLEN - 1] = '\0';
        inputStream[i].leftRow = leftRow;
        inputStream[i].rightRow = leftRow;
    }

    inputStream[i].leftRow = -1;

    readCycles++;
    (*inputSize) = NREAD;
    (*eof) = readCycles > READCYCLES;

    return inputStream;

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    short eof = 0;
    unsigned long int inputSize = 0;
    MatePair* inputStream = NULL;

    while (!eof){
        inputStream = readStream(inputStream, &eof, &inputSize);
        free(inputStream);
        inputStream = NULL;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I forgot to mention that, but before posting here, instead of calling free(inputStream), I tried invoking freeMemory(inputStream). Not sure if it's the correct way of doing it, though.

```
void freeMemory(MatePair* memblock){

    for ( ; memblock->leftRow != 1; memblock++){
        free(memblock -> leftDNA);
        free(memblock -> leftQuality);
        free(memblock -> rightDNA);
        free(memblock -> rightQuality);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try adding checks for all your `malloc` calls and run the program with valgrind. Also not your problem, but `r = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1)` is always going to be `0` unless you add a cast to `double` before dividing.

Comment: You have several memory leaks here, where are the memory allocated for inputstream[i].leftDNA etc released.

Comment: Yes I already noticed the (double) thing, forget to modify that yet because I was more worried with the memory leak thing :)

Comment: I would recommend recode the DNA sequences as char arrays instead (e.g. char leftDNA[SEQLEN]). That way you can allocate the struct array in one go, instead of doing it in many steps. To skip dynamic memory allocation altogether, declare the struct array on the stack just prior to the readStream() call, and pass it to readStream(). I am assuming your system is not an embedded system, and can handle ~300 kb on the stack.

Comment: The problem is that readStream() is only a debug stub, in the final application I won't know the value in SEQLEN until I read (and process) the first line of the first text file, so as far as I know that's the only way of doing it, isn't it? (I may be wrong, it has been some years since my last program in C and I've never been an expert with it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not freeing all members allocated within the read loop, hence you're losing memory eahc time.  Remember, you have to free everything you allocate with a malloc, not just your array.

Ok, Just look at your edit, and your freeMemory is still wrong.  Try this;

```
void freeMemory(MatePair* inputStream)
{
    for (i = 0; i < NREAD; i++){
        free(inputStream[i].leftDNA);
        free(inputStream[i].leftQuality);
        free(inputStream[i].rightDNA);
        free(inputStream[i].rightQuality);
    }
    free (inputStream);
  }
```

Your free(memblock) was in the loop, which it shouldn't have been, and I'd tend to use the same iteration sequence on freeing as mallocing.  You also need to error check after each malloc, and decide what to do with a NULL at that point.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that, edited my post. Not sure it's the right way to do it, however.

Comment: Okay, seems both you and Stan were right, as I suspected by myself. With the freeMemory() function the application crashed because I was checking if leftRow != 1, which means that freed only the first two structures. Damn typo!! It should have been -1... Thank you both for your help and sorry for the silly question...

Answer (score 3):

Memory leaks. How many 'malloc()' you have called, how many 'free()' you must use to free all allocated memory on the heap.

Thus,

```
inputStream[i].leftDNA = (char*) malloc (SEQLEN);
inputStream[i].rightDNA = (char*) malloc (SEQLEN);
inputStream[i].leftQuality = (char*) malloc (SEQLEN);
inputStream[i].rightQuality = (char*) malloc (SEQLEN);
```

these 'malloc()' functions must be paired with free().

Comment: Besides, some pitfalls are found in your program. First, in `if(inputStream == NULL){(*eof) = 1; return;}`, 'return' may be 'return NULL'; Second, maybe you should handle the problem when malloc() fails.

Comment: eof = 1 should end the program itself by failing the while loop check, that's why I do not bother the return statement.

Comment: However, that's not a good program style :) Readers will feel confused if they don't go through the whole program~